# Java access variables in arguments

Tags: java, variables, pointers, arguments

I would like to be able to access a variable passed to my method.  I know C might have has some kind of way to pass the address of something as an argument, then refer to that as a pointer and be able to use the variable.  Anyway, here's an example.

```
void myFunction(address to variable) {
    *variable = "example";
}
```

Then call it as:

```
myFunction(&somevariable);
```

Comment: Passing by reference is the term. And yes, the mutable objects are just like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to pass arguments by reference or by pointer in Java, so the only way to achieve the effect that you would like is passing a *mutable* object, and changing its value inside the method that you call:

```
public class ChangeableInt {
    private int number;
    public ChangeableInt(int value) {number = value;}
    public int get() {return number;}
    public void set(int value) {number = value;}
}
```

With this class in hand, you can do this:

```
void myFunction(ChangeableInt arg) {
   arg.set(42);
}
...
ChangeableInt val = new ChangeableInt(123);
myFunction(val);
System.out.println(val.get()); // prints 42
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a simple wrapper template class...

```
class ObjWrapper<T> {
  T value;

  void setValue(T val) {
    value=val;
  }

  T getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
 class Myclass{
    int x=15;

    System.out.println(x) //15

    public static void main(String... ){

    Myclass obj = new Myclass()
    Myclass newRef =  method(obj)
    System.out.println(newRef.x)   //20




    }
   static Myclass method(Myclass ref){
       ref.x=20

    return ref
  }  
    }//class
```

Note that in 'obj' is a reference to the object resides somewhere in heap.